# Need to provide dynamic content on PHPmailer attachment

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to use the variable content on the addattchment in phpmailer. please help us to know the syntax. I have used below syntax but not sending mail with attachment.

```
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $mail->AddAttachment (''.$name.'.pdf');
        if(!$mail->Send())
```

if i use without variable as ('filename.pdf'). sends mail with attachment.

Comment: Syntax is way too complicated, but technically correct. You should simply use `$mail->AddAttachment($name . '.pdf');`.

Comment: This being said, you should probably check if the value of `$name` is correct. Also, I am not sure about the context of this code, but letting people arbitrarily choose files from your server is not the best from the security point of view. You should validate the value of `$name`.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó since it is calling filename gowtham.pdf, can i have space as you mentioned?

Comment: My code and your code are equivalent, I just cleaned it up for you. But both will produce the same string / filename. There will be no space in the filename, those spaces you see are just before and after the concatenation operator (.) for better readablility.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó okay, but still same, i am able to receive the mail without attachment.   ```$mail->AddAttachment($customerName . '.pdf');
        if(!$mail->Send()) ```

Comment: As I wrote earlier: you should check what you get in `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó i get just string "gowtham" and i am having the file name as gowtham.pdf in same folder. i am expecting to take the file as "gowtham.pdf"    that $name works fine in subject and body with html

Comment: any guess why it is not pick up in addattachment and it works in subject $subj = ''.$customerName.' INVOICE NO. '.$order_id.' BILLING';

Comment: anyone can help me to get this solution?

Comment: Are you saying that if you hardcode the name (like this: `$mail->AddAttachment('gowtham.pdf')`) then it works?